# Как установить свой Click звук в программе по умолчанию?

Tags: java, android

В моей программе много активити. На каждую активити создавать новый `MediaPlayer` мне кажется не лучшее решение. Нашел такой метод:

```
view.playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);
```

но он использует стандартный "click" звук. Мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии на любую кнопку проигрывался мой звук.

Как это делают например в играх? Неужели каждый раз создают `MediaPlayer`, или что-то типа того?

Answer (score 2):

Можно создать свой класс, например, `CustomSoundButton`, который будет унаследован от класса `Button` и переопределить в нем конструктор и определить метод `playSound()`:

```
public class CustomSoundButton extends Button {
    private SoundPool mSoundPool;
    private int mSoundId;

    public CustomSoundButton(Context context) {
        super(context);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            createNewSoundPool();
        } else {
            createOldSoundPool();
        }

        try {
            mSoundId = mSoundPool.load(this.getContext().getAssets().openFd("my_sound.ogg"), 1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // handle exception
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    protected void createNewSoundPool(){
        AudioAttributes attributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_GAME)
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                .build();
        mSoundPool = new SoundPool.Builder()
                .setAudioAttributes(attributes)
                .build();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    protected void createOldSoundPool(){
        mSoundPool = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    }

    public void playSound() {
        mSoundPool.play(mSoundId, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
    }
}
```

В конструкторе происходит инициализация объекта `mSoundPool`, который, собственно и отвечает за воспроизведение звука. Далее инициализируется объект `mSoundId` – идентификатора мелодии.

Далее, в методе `onClick(...)` интерфейса `View.OnClickListener`, кроме прочих действий, Вы можете вызвать метод `playSound()`:

```
mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mButton.playSound();
        // others actions
    }
});
```

Класс `CustomSoundButton` можно определить таким образом, чтобы он воспроизводил различные мелодии в зависимости от переданного в метод `playSound(...)` идентификатора.

**Чем хорош данный подход?**  – Вы один раз определяете необходимое Вам поведение, а потом просто вызываете один метод.

Comment: А еще здесь можно переопределить setOnClickListener и  в нем вызывал бы метод playSound();                                                            //@Override
    public void setOnClickListener(OnClickListener l) {
        super.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mButton.playSound();
                l.onClick(view);
            }
        });
    }

Comment: @artemiygreg, Да, можно и так.

Comment: Спасибо. Уже не первый раз выручаешь!